# Specify dynamic method for interface resolution on type resolving in Autofac

Tags: c#, logging, inversion-of-control, autofac, constructor-injection

Many of my classes are accepting some `ILogger` interface.

This interface is implemented by a class that can accept the context it should log.

So in practice when passing `ILogger`, what I want to pass is `new Logger(nameof(<type>)`, depending on the `<type>` we are currently resolving.

Can this be done in some sort in Autofac without specifically stating the contructor parameters for each type? since this is always the behavior I want to achieve when Autofac resolves `ILogger` injection parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a formal example in `Autofac` documentation:

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/examples/log4net.html